Iced Rust button DefaultStyle compiling error
I'm trying to do the iced rust tutorial (from the book) but i encountered a compiling error hen i tried to make a button:
use iced::widget::button;

fn main() {
  let mut counter = Counter { value: 0 };
  counter.update(Message::Increment);
  counter.update(Message::Increment);
  counter.update(Message::Decrement);

  let inc = button("+");
  let dec = button("-");
  
}


struct Counter{
  value: i64,
}

impl Counter{
  fn update(&mut self, msg:Message){
    match msg{
      Message::Increment=>{
        self.value +=1;
      }
      Message::Decrement=>{
        self.value -=1;
      }
    }
  }
}

enum Message{
  Increment,
  Decrement,
}

In particular the line let inc = button("+"); make this error:

   Compiling note v0.1.0 (/home/gattolfo/Documents/rust/note)
error[E0283]: type annotations needed for `iced::widget::Button<'_, _, _, _>`
   --> src/main.rs:12:7
    |
12  |   let inc = button("+");
    |       ^^^   ----------- type must be known at this point
    |
    = note: cannot satisfy `_: iced::widget::button::DefaultStyle`
    = help: the following types implement trait `iced::widget::button::DefaultStyle`:
              Theme
              iced::Color
              iced::widget::button::Appearance
note: required by a bound in `button`
   --> /home/gattolfo/.cargo/git/checkouts/iced-f01cba4d5e61fd0a/cdb18e6/widget/src/helpers.rs:120:12
    |
116 | pub fn button<'a, Message, Theme, Renderer>(
    |        ------ required by a bound in this function
...
120 |     Theme: button::DefaultStyle + 'a,
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `button`
help: consider giving `inc` an explicit type, where the type for type parameter `Theme` is specified
    |
12  |   let inc: iced::widget::Button<'_, Message, Theme, Renderer> = button("+");
    |          ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0283`.
error: could not compile `note` (bin "note") due to 1 previous error

What i'm doing wrong? I'm not able to find other on the book.

It seems like the book is quite outdated. You might have more luck checking out the official samples.

@frankenapps thank you, i'm gonna check this!
EDIT:
Just kidding, also the examples are outdated apparently, they use Sandbox that if i'm not wrong is outfated

@AmedeoBraggio I haven't used Iced in a few months, but I don't think Sandbox is deprecated. At least, the documentation doesn't mention that.

@AmedeoBraggio I posted a link to the examples for version 0.12.1. On the latest master branch, the examples do not use Sandbox the same way as was done before. Maybe you should specify your iced version and browse around the repository a bit.

@frankenapps yeah, thank you now works, probably i had a bad import :(

So the error message is quite unhelpful in this case (not to any fault of iced), but the fix is very easy.
You just have to change the:
  let inc = button("+");
  let dec = button("-");

to
  let inc = button(text("+"));
  let dec = button(text("-"));

Which in this case you are just wrapping the string in the text type. This is because of the constraint on fn view where it must return Element<'_, Message> is not satisfied in the case of button(&str) but is satisfied in the case of button(text(&str)) (because button(&str) does not impl Into<Element> but button(text(&str) does.
I believe there is / was a pull request on the iced repo, to make it work as you had, but I couldn't find it.

It says "type must be known at this point". The type for this isn't just iced::widget::Button, it is iced::widget::Button<'_, Message, Theme, Renderer>. The error appears because it isn't specified what messages button can return; not specifying theme and renderer won't return a fatal error. As long as you want to create a variable, the solution is:
let inc: Button<Message> = button("+");
let dec: Button<Message> = button("-");

